# stringstream unsigned conversion broken?

Tags: c++, iostream, stringstream

Consider this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream stream( "-1" );
    unsigned short n = 0;
    stream >> n;
    assert( stream.fail() && n == 0 );
    std::cout << "can't convert -1 to unsigned short" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried this on gcc (version 4.0.1 Apple Inc. build 5490) on OS X 10.5.6 and the assertion is true; it fails to convert -1 to an unsigned short.

In Visual Studio 2005 (and 2008) however, the assertion fails and the resulting value of n is the same as what you would expect from an compiler generated implicit conversion - i.e "-1" is 65535, "-2" is 65534, etc.  But then it gets weird at "-32769" which converts to 32767.

Who's right and who's wrong here? (And what the hell's going on with -32769??)

Comment: Can you check the default format flags set on istringstream on Mac using flags()?

Comment: as we don't seem to be getting a flood of answers, I've posted a slighly modified version on clc++m - http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/97475b21515462c9#

Comment: Thanks Neil. Gosh, it gets complicated!  I can see it's not so as easy as I had once hoped.

Comment: THis has been confirmed as a g++  bug - see http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39802

Comment: Nice! Just have to wait for Apple to catch up! Cheers Neil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour claimed by GCC in Max Lybbert's post is based on the tables om the C++ Standard that map iostream behaviour onto printf/scanf converters (or at least that;'s my reading). However, the scanf behaviour of g++ seems to be different from the istream behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;;

int main()
{
    unsigned short n = 0;
    if ( ! sscanf( "-1", "%hu", &n ) ) {
        cout << "conversion failed\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << n << endl;
    }
}
```

actually prints 65535.

Comment: THis reply on clc++m http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/97475b21515462c9/ce369a327fa39243#ce369a327fa39243 confirms that C++ input is defined interms of C input - but comes to a rather different conclusion!

Comment: not sure i agree with that guy. strtoul says that the resulting value is negated. when 1 negated for unsigned short it is USHRT_MAX (modulo arithmetic), which is what MSVC returns correctly. Not sure why he says it should return 1 ?

Comment: No, I think he was a bit off-beam there. But what's your take on the original question?

Comment: i'm going to agree with that dude on the usenet, apart from the last part as i stated :) (posted an answer on that thread. let's see when ops release it :)) anyway, i just checked with gcc4.4, and its op>> also returns USHRT_MAX. So i suspect that bug is already fixed :)

Answer (score 3):

First, reading the string "-1" as a negative number is locale dependent (it would be possible for a locale to identify negative numbers by enclosing them in parenthesis).  [Your default standard is the "classic" C locale](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/3rd_loc.pdf):

> By far the dominant use of *locales* is implicitly, in stream I/O. Each *istream* and *ostream* has its own *locale*. The *locale* of a stream is by default the global *locale* at the time of the stream’s creation (page 6). ...
>
> Initially, the global locale is the standard C locale, *locale::classic()* (page 11).

<strike>According to the GCC guys, [numeric overflow is allowed to fail the stream input operation](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-prs/2002-01/msg00693.html) (talking about negative numbers that overflowed a signed int):</strike>

> [T]he behaviour of libstdc++-v3 is strictly standard conforming. ... When the read is attempted it does *not* fit in a signed int i, and it fails.

Thanks to another answer, [a bug was filed and this behavior changed](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39802):

> Oops, apparently we never parsed correctly negative values for unsigned. The
>   fix is simple. ...
>
> Fixed in mainline, will be fixed in 4.4.1 too.

Second, although integer overflow is generally predictable, I believe it's [officially undefined behavior](http://dobbscodetalk.com/index.php?option=com_myblog&show=A-parable-about-undefined-behavior.html&Itemid=29), so while I can't say why -32769" converts to 32767, I think it's allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream stream( "-1" );
    std::cout << "flags: " << (unsigned long)stream.flags() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried this on my VS2005:

```
flags: 513
```

and on [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/Aiwmy0ZH) (which I think uses g++) this gives:

```
flags: 4098
```

This tells me that gcc uses a different default `fmtflags`. Since `fmtflags` control what conversions are possible you are getting different results.

Comment: Clarification: codepad C++ compilation uses g++ 4.1.2. I think Mac's istringstream is likely to have the same or a similar fmtflags (but different from VS2005).

Comment: Couldn't this just mean that the actual implementation values of fmtflags differ between the c++ implementations?

Comment: I don''t know which, if either is the error. The standard seems to say that this is locale dependent, and my knowledge of the ins & outs of locales is about zero :-(

Comment: Yes, I too have seen that it is locale dependent. Maybe tomorrow I will give this a try with a Mac proper!

Comment: @Neil: yes, it looks like gcc and VS have different implementation values for the fmtflags. I get the same results as dirkgently - 513 and 4098. Looking at the implementation the only flags set on both are dec and skipws.

Comment: @Steve: If they have the same locale, then this is a bug with g++.

Comment: FWIW, I get the same g++ behaviour as in the question using MinGW 3.4.2 on windows

Comment: Is this with std=c++98 and related switches on?

Comment: @dirkgently: both are using locale "C" (assuming std::locale().name() is the correct thing to do?). With due respect, why do you think g++ is wrong, and not VS?

Comment: One of them is broken. The conversion looks legal.

Comment: Hmmmm. VS aligns closer to what you'd expect from implicit conversions, but then the stream conversion really does fail for n < "-65535" and > "65535".  Aaargggh!!!