# stringstream fails "streaming" negative values in unsigned types?

Tags: c++, std, stringstream

I'm having same issue in Ubuntu 10.04 using gcc4.4, the same code works
fine on RH 5.5 using gcc4.1

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  std::stringstream myStream;
  myStream << "-123";

  unsigned int myUInt;
  myStream >> myUInt;

  if(myStream.fail()) {
    std::cout << "FAILED" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

doesn't give FAILED, I have already found this:

http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39802

where it stated that it was corrected in gcc4.1, not
sure the if that miss behave (unless I'm missing something)
is related to same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are expecting it to fail. sscanf() also doesn't fail, but reads the the number, and the C++ streams are supposed to work like the scanf functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    unsigned int n;
    if ( ! sscanf( "-1", "%ud", & n ) ) {
        printf( "fail\n" );
    }
    else {
        printf( "%ud", n );
    }
}
```

prints 4294967295d.

And see also [stringstream unsigned conversion broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786951/stringstream-unsigned-conversion-broken).

Comment: Because on RH5.4 with 4.1 compiler it fails. Also I'm not sure about the fact that stringstream has to behave like scanf. Not to mention the fact that boost::lexical_cast relies on the fact that it has to fail, indeed I discovered the stringstream not failing due the fact that boost::lexical_cast<unsigned int>("-123") is not throwing.

The link you posted states at the end that it will be fixed for 4.4.1 but actualy that code fails with 4.4.3

Comment: @kalman Yes, that's the bug!  It was in 4.1, and was fixed later. also, you can see from the other question that there is some debate about what the "correct2 behaviour is.

Comment: So you mean the fact stringstream fails in streaming "-123" in an unsigned type it was a bug and not a feature?

Comment: @kalman Do you expect if you read -1 into an unsigned int, it takes on the value UINT_MAX? If so, current behaviour (i.e. not failing) is correct.

Comment: No I expect same behave as I'm converting "XXXXXX" in an int.

Comment: Indeed I'm out of luck. Anyway, now I check with a type traits if the target type is an unsigned and then before to convert to the real target I convert it first to a double to check if it's negative and in case I throw a bad_cast....