# stringstream unsigned input validation

Tags: c++, validation, c++11

I'm writing part of program which parses and validates some user input in program console arguments. I choose to use stringstream for that purpose, but encounter a problem with unsigned types reading.

Next template is intended for reading requested type from given string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::stringstream;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<typename ValueType>
ValueType read_value(string s)
{   
    stringstream ss(s);
    ValueType res;
    ss >> res;
    if (ss.fail() or not ss.eof())
        throw string("Bad argument: ") + s;
    return res;
}
// +template specializations for strings, etc. 

int main(void)
{   
    cout << read_value<unsigned int>("-10") << endl;
}
```

In case type is unsigned and input string contains negative number I expect to see exception throw (caused by `ss.fail() = true`). But stringstream produces casted to unsigned type value (4294967286 in written sample).

How can be this sample fixed to achieve desired behavior (preferable without fallback to c functions)?
I understand that it can be done with simple first symbol check but I can put leading spaces for example. I can write own parser but don't believe that problem is so unpredictable and standard library unable to solve it.

Functions hidden in deep of stringstream operators for unsigned types are strtoull and strtoul. They work in described manner but *mentioned functions are low-level*. Why stringstream do not provide some validation level? (I just hope I'm wrong and it does but some movements required to enable this).

Comment: I saw this thread but there was a problem with inconsistent behavior in different compilers. And finally behavior on MS VS and modern GCC was just convert to unsigned representation as far as I understood.

Comment: Re-opened; the [linked duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786951/stringstream-unsigned-conversion-broken) only addresses C++03, but the behaviour changed in C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `num_get` facet to support the explicit check for signedness. Rejects any non-zero number beginning with a `'-'` (after white-spaces) for unsigned types and uses the default C locale's `num_get` to do the actual conversion.

```
#include <locale>
#include <istream>
#include <ios>
#include <algorithm>

template <class charT, class InputIterator = std::istreambuf_iterator<charT> >
class num_get_strictsignedness : public std::num_get <charT, InputIterator>
{
public:
    typedef charT char_type;
    typedef InputIterator iter_type;

    explicit num_get_strictsignedness(std::size_t refs = 0)
        : std::num_get<charT, InputIterator>(refs)
    {}
    ~num_get_strictsignedness()
    {}

private:
    #define DEFINE_DO_GET(TYPE) \
        virtual iter_type do_get(iter_type in, iter_type end,      \
            std::ios_base& str, std::ios_base::iostate& err,       \
            TYPE& val) const override                              \
        {  return do_get_templ(in, end, str, err, val);  }         // MACRO END

    DEFINE_DO_GET(unsigned short)
    DEFINE_DO_GET(unsigned int)
    DEFINE_DO_GET(unsigned long)
    DEFINE_DO_GET(unsigned long long)

    // not sure if a static locale::id is required..

    template <class T>
    iter_type do_get_templ(iter_type in, iter_type end, std::ios_base& str,
                           std::ios_base::iostate& err, T& val) const
    {
        using namespace std;

        if(in == end)
        {
            err |= ios_base::eofbit;
            return in;
        }

        // leading white spaces have already been discarded by the
        // formatted input function (via sentry's constructor)

        // (assuming that) the sign, if present, has to be the first character
        // for the formatting required by the locale used for conversion

        // use the "C" locale; could use any locale, e.g. as a data member

        // note: the signedness check isn't actually required
        //       (because we only overload the unsigned versions)
        bool do_check = false;
        if(std::is_unsigned<T>{} && *in == '-')
        {
            ++in;  // not required
            do_check = true;
        }

        in = use_facet< num_get<charT, InputIterator> >(locale::classic())
                 .get(in, end, str, err, val);

        if(do_check && 0 != val)
        {
            err |= ios_base::failbit;
            val = 0;
        }

        return in;
    }
};
```

Usage example:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::locale loc( std::locale::classic(),
                     new num_get_strictsignedness<char>() );
    std::stringstream ss("-10");
    ss.imbue(loc);
    unsigned int ui = 42;
    ss >> ui;
    std::cout << "ui = "<<ui << std::endl;
    if(ss)
    {
        std::cout << "extraction succeeded" << std::endl;
    }else
    {
        std::cout << "extraction failed" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Notes:

- the allocation on the free store is not required, you could use e.g. a (static) local variable where you initialize the ref counter with `1` in the ctor
- for every character type you want to support (like `char`, `wchar_t`, `charXY_t`), you need to add an own facet (can be different instantiations of the `num_get_strictsignedness` template)
- `"-0"` is accepted

Comment: I fail to understand how someone could *not* love the input/output and locale libraries [/sarcasm]

Comment: Everything is great! Except small thing mentioned in [gcc bugtracker](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39802) - it's rejecting "-0" string. I don't imply you should fix it, just making a note. Thanks for your answer, will try to use/upgrade it.

Comment: @AlexanderSergeev Fixed it ;) (though it has nothing to do with the gcc bug, it's similar, and easy to fix)

Comment: Really, quite easy to fix :)

Comment: @AlexanderSergeev Note I just discovered that the `eofbit` was overwritten. Fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Version disclaimer: The answer is different for C++03. The following deals with C++11.

First, let's analyse what's happening.

`ss >> res;` This calls `std::istream::operator>>(unsigned)`. In [istream.formatted.arithmetic]/1, the effects are defined as follows:

> These extractors behave as formatted input functions (as described in 27.7.2.2.1). After a sentry object is constructed, the conversion occurs as if performed by the following code fragment:
>
> ```
> typedef num_get< charT,istreambuf_iterator<charT,traits> > numget;
> iostate err = iostate::goodbit;
> use_facet< numget >(loc).get(*this, 0, *this, err, val);
> setstate(err);
> ```
>
> In the above fragment, `loc` stands for the private member of the `basic_ios` class.

Following *formatted input functions* to [istream::sentry], the main effect of the `sentry` object here is to consume leading white-space characters. It also prevents executing of the code shown above in case of an error (stream is in failed / eof state).

The used locale is the `"C"` locale. Rationale:

For a the `stringstream` constructed via `stringstream ss(s);`, the locale of that iostream is the current global locale at the time of construction (that's guaranteed deep down in the rabbit hole at [ios.base.locales]/4). As the global locale hasn't been changed in the OP's program, [locale.cons]/2 specifies the "classic" locale, i.e. the `"C"` locale.

`use_facet< numget >(loc).get` uses the member function `num_get<char>::get(iter_type in, iter_type end, ios_base&, ios_base::iostate& err, unsigned int& v) const;` specified in [locale.num.get] (note the `unsigned int`, everything is still fine). The details of the string -> `unsigned int` conversion for the "C" locale are lengthy and described in [facet.num.get.virtuals]. Some interesting details:

- For an unsigned integer value, the function `strtoull` is used.
- If the conversion fails, `ios_base::failbit` is assigned to `err`. Specifically: "The numeric value to be stored can be one of: [...] the most negative representable value or zero for an unsigned integer type, if the field represents a value too large negative to be represented in val. `ios_base::failbit` is assigned to `err`."

We need to go to C99, 7.20.1.4 for the definition of `strtoull`, under paragraph 5:

> If the subject sequence begins with a minus sign, the value resulting from
>   the conversion is negated (in the return type).

and under paragraph 8:

> If the correct value is outside the range of representable values, `LONG_MIN`, `LONG_MAX`, `LLONG_MIN`, `LLONG_MAX`, `ULONG_MAX`, or `ULLONG_MAX` is returned (according to the return type and sign of the value, if any), and the value of the macro `ERANGE` is stored in `errno`

It seems that it has been debated in the past if negative values are considered valid input for `strotoul`. In any case, the problem lies here with this function. A quick check on gcc says that it's considered valid input, and therefore the behaviour you observed.

---

Historic note: C++03

C++03 used `scanf` inside the `num_get` conversion. Unfortunately, I'm not quite sure (yet) how the conversion for `scanf` is specified, and under which circumstances errors occur.

---

An explicit error check:

We can manually insert that check either by using a signed value for conversion and testing `<0`, or we look for the `-` character (which isn't a good idea because of possible localization issues).

Comment: In my humble opinion, a negative value should **not** be considered valid input for `strtoul`, because the sign of the value is considered for the error check in 7.20.1.4/8. But I don't want to pick a quarrel with the C folks ;)

Comment: Regretfully, but using of signed type first isn't cure: for example in case `ValueType = char` difference between signed and unsigned types is pretty possible to rise up with user interaction. So, we can use most-long type, but in many cases it's overkill. And flexibility of templates will be lost.
According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get) there is a character validation on stage 2. Why not restrict `-` appearance if is_signed<type> fails? Or something like that?

Comment: @AlexanderSergeev Yes, you cannot directly use the signed equivalents of unsigned types. (In your example, `"128"` is not a valid input for an 8-bit `signed char`.) You had to use signed integral types that have a greater positive range than the original unsigned types. That can be done with metaprogramming, but it's not pretty.

Comment: "Why not restrict - appearance if is_signed<type> fails?" You could indeed do that for your own locale/`num_get` facet. I'll try to make an example.

Comment: There are some restrictions on type capacity growing. As far as we are using generic (meta) programming we must correctly process `unsigned long long` type, for example. And turning on long arithmetic in this case is not an option I believe.