# Ways of converting wstring to double with error checking

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, double

I need to convert a wide string to double number. Presumably, the string is holding a number and nothing else (maybe some whitespaces). If the string contains anything else, an error should be indicated. So I can't use `stringstream` - it will extract a number without indicating an error if the string contained something else.

`wcstod` seems like a perfect solution, but it works wrong on Android (GCC 4.8, NDK r9). What other options can I try?

Comment: Use [`std::stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) it throws exception in case of bad input.

Comment: "it will extract a number without indicating an error if the string contained something else." Huh? If the extraction fails, `failbit` should be set. (If you enable `stringstream`'s exceptions, you'll get an exception as well.)

Comment: @MM.: It's a wrapper around `strtod`, I believe, and my input is wide string.

Comment: @DyP: if it fails an exception will be thrown BUT there is no error with this string, and I need an error here: "123 asf".

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Then look for eof as well, as demonstrated in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18917167/420683).

Comment: Get the source and fix the wcstod for Android

Comment: @Neil: I think getting getting my fix back into AOSP repository will take years. Not to mention I hate non-ASCII strings, and this particular function needs to be implemented very carefully :)

Comment: @VioletGiraffe I meant fix wcstod and call it my_wcstod and use it locally, no need to send it off to be 'official'.  If it mostly works then it might be the easiest.  Also, any wcstod source from anywhere would work wouldn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `stringstream`, then use [`std:ws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws) to check that any remaining characters on the stream are only whitespace:

```
double parseNum (const std::wstring& s)
{
    std::wistringstream iss(s);
    double parsed;
    if ( !(iss >> parsed) )
    {
        // couldn't parse a double
        return 0;
    }
    if ( !(iss >> std::ws && iss.eof()) )
    {
        // something after the double that wasn't whitespace
        return 0;
    }
    return parsed;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << parseNum(L"  123  \n  ") << '\n';
    std::cout << parseNum(L"  123 asd \n  ") << '\n';
}
```

prints

```
$ ./a.out 
123
0
```

(I've just returned `0` in the error case as something quick and easy for my example. You probably want to `throw` or something).

There are of course other options too. I just felt your assessment was unfair on `stringstream`. By the way, this is one of the few cases where you actually *do* want to check `eof()`.

Edit: Ok, I added the `w`s and `L`s to use `wchar_t`s.

Edit: Here's what the second `if` conceptually looks like expanded out. May help to understand why it is correct.

```
if ( iss >> std::ws )
{ // successfully read some (possibly none) whitespace
    if ( iss.eof() )
    { // and hit the end of the stream, so we know there was no garbage
        return parsed;
    }
    else
    { // something after the double that wasn't whitespace
        return 0;
    }
}
else
{ // something went wrong trying to read whitespace
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `wistringstream` and `wstring`. Other than that, +1.

Comment: What's the meaning of `if ( !(iss >> parsed) )` check? `operator>>` returns `istream&`, not bool. Is `istream` convertible to bool?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Roughly, yes, for exactly this purpose. In C++03, [`std::basic_ios`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios) had an [`operator void*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) which returned a null pointer if `fail()` returned `true`. As of 2011, it has an `explicit operator bool`, which [behaves like this](http://chris-sharpe.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/contextually-converted-to-bool.html). Basically, it reads, and then checks that the read did not fail.

Comment: Note the same conversion happens further down as well, in `iss >> std::ws && ...`.

Comment: I believe the condition is wrong here. Should be `if (!(iss >> std::ws || iss.eof()))`, right?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe No. If it was an OR, then we could successfully read some whitespace, and so not enter the block, but because we short circuited checking that we actually read the whole stream, we still have some garbage left. The point of this check is that trailing whitespace *is* allowed, but *nothing else*.

Comment: Right, thanks for clarification. Then the code doesn't work as expected, I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe I have expanded out that condition in my answer.